# TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined in Node js while uploading file

Tags: javascript, node.js, formidable

I am new to node js.

I was trying to upload a file, it is showing some path error. Below is my code.

```html
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        console.log(files);
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = '/var/www/html/Node-Js/img/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Here I have installed the formidable module.It's installed.
I am getting this below error, please have a look.

```html
/var/www/html/Node-Js/file_upload.js:11
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at /var/www/html/Node-Js/file_upload.js:11:40
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Node-Js/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:107:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (/var/www/html/Node-Js/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:557:8)
    at Object.end (/var/www/html/Node-Js/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:247:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Node-Js/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:132:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
```

Comment: You need to check `files` before attempting to access it.  As @HemilPatel noted (but was unable to comment) and you confirmed `files == null {}` - you can't access the '.filetoupload' property of `null`.   So you need to find where your files *are* going to.

Comment: what is the result of the console log right before the `var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path`?

Comment: @mthrsj its coming null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting **null{}** in the `console.log(files)` is the reason behind this particular error. `Files`is coming null so the `files.filetoupload` will be undefined and that's why `files.filetoupload.path` can't be found. I would say please find why the `files` is coming null. Once you will be started getting data in files this error will be solved.

Comment: I guess there might some issue in uploading, I refreshed properly checked now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after looking at the logs I realized that path and name don't exist under that name so try replacing :

```
var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
var newpath = '/var/www/html/Node-Js/img/' + files.filetoupload.name;
```

with :

```
var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;
var newpath = '/var/www/html/Node-Js/img/' + files.filetoupload.originalFilename;
```

This worked for me so I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

use files[0]

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        console.log(files);
      var oldpath = files[0].filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = '/var/www/html/Node-Js/img/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and after looking closely into my code, I found that I used different name to get files in **server.js** then the one I mentioned in **html file**

I named file element in HTML

> name="invoices" // input type=file

In **server.js** is used

> filetoupload

So, if anyone face similar issue please look into your code especially the name given to HTML elements.